# Angular StackBlitz app won't recognize path aliases in tsconfig

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I am having trouble getting an Angular stackblitz app to use the path aliases.

Using Angular 15.2.3

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["app/components/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["app/pages/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

If you remove the "paths": entry it works fine, otherwise it forever loads.

My stackblitz example app - [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9epthq?file=tsconfig.json)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I found a relevant thread on github, seems like this is a known issue. Maybe stackblitz still doesn't support custom paths?  - https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/220

Comment: Someone has it working here for an earlier version of Angular 15. I can't see the difference... - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tzu5g?file=tsconfig.json